# pdflatex hangs when compiling some pdf files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, python, matplotlib

I'm using TeXstudio an a Mac and have found that some pgf files (obtained from python's Matplotlib), cause the compilation to hang.  Also, when I run pdflatex from the terminal, it hangs on:

```
[13] (./plots/my_plot.pgf
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd)
```

`t1cmss.fd` appears to be related to fonts.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: how can we know if you show no code? there are any number of ways of coding an infinite loop in tex. Presumably your document is looping.

Comment: if you can  make a small but complete document that just inputs `my_plot.pgf` and loops you should be eble to add the complete test document to your question so someone can debug.